# PHP mail, from field

Tags: php, email, header

Please help.  When I send email from my contact from, the sender is shown as 'From: (name of web host) on behalf of (visitor email)' - how do I remove it so it only shows the visitor's email.

I'm using shared hosting, so not sure if it's a problem on their server setting.

The codes I've used are below:

```
 //send the email

 $to = $your_email;
 $subject = $visitorMessageSubject;
 $from = $visitorEmail ;
 $body = "Test \n\n".

 $headers = "From: " .$visitorEmail . PHP_EOL;
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $from" . PHP_EOL;
 $headers .= "Return-Path: $from" . PHP_EOL;
 $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

 mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f $from");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure `$visitorEmail` has a value. It currently does not.

Comment: The input for all the variables are coming from the form fields.

Comment: @JohnConde  if (empty($_POST["visitorEmail"])) {
     $visitorEmailErr = "*Email is required";
   } else {
     $visitorEmail = test_input($_POST["visitorEmail"]);
  
   $sanVisitorEmail = filter_var( $visitorEmail, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  
     // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
     if (!filter_var($sanVisitorEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
      $visitorEmailErr = "Invalid email format";
     }
   }

Comment: echo $from   .................. ?